# PyQt5 looping navigation bar troubles

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm working on a script that has a scrolling navigation menu on the bottom, navigated by a rotary encoder.  There should only be 3 icons shown at once, with the center icon always larger and as the user reaches the end of the list it should smoothly continue back from the beginning.  This works properly until I reach the end of the list, but then it breaks the pattern for the last and first members of the list.

IE, it should go like this:

```
0 [1] 2
1 [2] 3
2 [3] 4
3 [4] 5
4 [5] 0
5 [0] 1
```

But the actual pattern I'm getting is:

```
0 [1] 2
1 [2] 3
2 [3] 4
3 [4] 5
0 4 [5]
[0] 1 5
```

Here's the full code

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import board
import busio
from adafruit_seesaw.seesaw import Seesaw
from adafruit_seesaw.rotaryio import IncrementalEncoder

# Rotary Encoder setup
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
ss = Seesaw(i2c, addr=0x49)
encoder = IncrementalEncoder(ss)
last_position = encoder.position

class RotaryInterface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowFullScreen)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")
        self.font_small = QFont('Symbola', 30)
        self.font_large = QFont('Symbola', 50)

        self.symbols_with_effects = [
            ("\U0001F31F", "Glowing Star"),
            ("\U0001F3A8", "Artist Palette"),
            ("\U0001F680", "Rocket"),
            ("\U0001F340", "Four Leaf Clover"),
            ("\U0001F308", "Rainbow"),
            ("\U0001F319", "Crescent Moon")
        ]

        self.labels = [QLabel(sym[0], self) for sym in self.symbols_with_effects]
        self.symbol_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.symbol_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.symbol_layout)
        for i, label in enumerate(self.labels):
            label.setFont(self.font_small)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom | Qt.AlignHCenter)
            self.symbol_layout.addWidget(label, 0, i)

        self.selected = 1
        self.visible_icons = self.calculateVisibleIcons()
        self.updateDisplay()

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.checkEncoder)
        self.timer.start(100)

        self.close_button = QPushButton(chr(0x274E), self)
        self.close_button.setFont(QFont('Symbola', 50))
        self.close_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: red; border: 0px; }"
                                        "QPushButton:hover, QPushButton:pressed, QPushButton:focus {"
                                        "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: red; border: 0px;}")
        self.close_button.setFlat(True)
        self.close_button.setGeometry(700, 0, 100, 100)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def calculateVisibleIcons(self):
        num_icons = len(self.symbols_with_effects)
    
        # When selected is the first icon
        if self.selected == 0:
            return [num_icons - 1, self.selected, self.selected + 1]
    
        # When selected is the last icon
        elif self.selected == num_icons - 1:
            return [self.selected - 1, self.selected, 0]

        # For all other cases
        else:
            return [self.selected - 1, self.selected, self.selected + 1]

    def updateDisplay(self):
        # Hide all labels initially
        for label in self.labels:
            label.hide()

        # Show and set font for visible icons
        for index in self.visible_icons:
            label = self.labels[index]
            label.show()
            if index == self.selected:
                label.setFont(self.font_large)
            else:
                label.setFont(self.font_small)

    def checkEncoder(self):
        global last_position
        position = encoder.position
        if position != last_position:
            delta = position - last_position
            self.selected = (self.selected + delta) % len(self.symbols_with_effects)
            self.visible_icons = self.calculateVisibleIcons()
            self.updateDisplay()
            last_position = position

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = RotaryInterface()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried updating the `calculateVisibleIcons` method to explicitly handle the end and beginning but that doesn't correct the issue

```
    def calculateVisibleIcons(self):
        num_icons = len(self.symbols_with_effects)
        
        # When selected is the first icon
        if self.selected == 0:
            return [num_icons - 1, self.selected, self.selected + 1]
        
        # When selected is the last icon
        elif self.selected == num_icons - 1:
            return [self.selected - 1, self.selected, 0]

        # For all other cases
        else:
            return [self.selected - 1, self.selected, self.selected + 1]
```

It seems like I'm making a simple logic error here but I can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh!  Just figured it out.  The fix was to explicity manage the positions of the qlabel widgets in the qgridlayout during the wraparound, ensuring they were repositioned according to the proper order and refreshed.

```
def updateDisplay(self):
    # Hide all labels initially and remove them from the layout
    for label in self.labels:
        label.hide()
        self.symbol_layout.removeWidget(label)

    # Reposition and show the visible icons in the layout
    for i, index in enumerate(self.visible_icons):
        label = self.labels[index]
        label.show()
        if index == self.selected:
            label.setFont(self.font_large)
        else:
            label.setFont(self.font_small)
        # Update the position in the grid layout
        self.symbol_layout.addWidget(label, 0, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just changing the visibility of widgets, not their order.

When you add the labels to the layout, they are in this order:

```py
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
```

If you then make visible labels 4, 5 and 0, the widgets are still in their place:

```py
[0] --- --- --- [4] [5]
```

The order in which you hide or show widgets is completely irrelevant.

In order to "shift" the position of labels, you should remove and add them again to the layout.

Note that you should always use a *dedicated* layout in these situations, which must not be possibly shared with other widgets.

QGridLayout is also not indicated for such purposes, and a horizontal box layout is more appropriate, as item index ordering is automatically adjusted upon removal or insertion.

```py
class RotaryInterface(QWidget):
    ...
    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.symbol_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.symbol_layout)
        ...

    def updateDisplay(self):
        # Only hide and remove from the layout the labels that
        # aren't meant to be shown, no point in hiding all of them
        for i, label in enumerate(self.labels):
            if not i in self.visible_icons:
                label.hide()
                self.symbol_layout.removeWidget(label)

        lastIndex = -1
        for index in self.visible_icons:
            label = self.labels[index]
            if index == self.selected:
                label.setFont(self.font_large)
            else:
                label.setFont(self.font_small)
            if index < lastIndex:
                self.symbol_layout.removeWidget(label)
            self.symbol_layout.addWidget(label)
            label.show()
            lastIndex = index
```

The concept is that if the index of the "new" widget is lower than the previous one, it should be removed and added at the "end" of the layout.